# trying to get the result of xml in to the header location in php

Tags: php

I've a very simple question: trying to get the result of xml in to the header location, but I'm getting error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'
I also found the the link there explain how to solve the problem,
[syntax error,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/22316776#22316776)

I coulden't get any help from there

Here is my code:

```
   <?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://test.com/music.xml?id=55571") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
//echo $xml->item['mp3'];
header("Location: ".$xml->item['mp3']; ?>
```

I'm not getting any respons in header loc, just error :(
when I'm echoing it's working good.

Please help me out :)

Comment: Why you are using header() then?

Comment: @BitsPlease to download the file.

Comment: You want xml  file to get forcefully download?

Comment: @Naga still getting error :/

Comment: @BitsPlease Yes. but the link is forcing to download by it self. i just want to redirect. that i can use it in online mp3 player also:P

Comment: @BitsPlease any idea?

Comment: @Naga Could u find some other solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just Small Typo?

```
header("Location: ".$xml->item['mp3']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close header ")" missing

Your Code

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://cdn.biatik.com/api/android/2/music.xml?id=55571") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
header("Location: ".$xml->item['mp3']; ?>
```

MY Code

```
header("Location: ".$xml->item['mp3'] );
```

Comment: OMG how could forget that ? Thankyou for both of you guys @Maulik and bits-please